# I have 3 articles in a row and the third article it's greater than other two

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Best News Ever</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="discription" content="This page is a website to learn HTML">
    <meta name="keywords" content="hmtl5,udemy,learn code">

    <meta name="author" content="Kostas Boukas">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

</head>

<body>

    <header id="main-header">
         <h1 id="site-title">Best News Ever!</h1>
       </header>

       <section id="top-stories">
         <article>
           <div class="article-image" style="background:url(srf.jpg)"> </div>
           <h3 class="h">Surfing all day</h3>
           <p>All you need about surfing<a href="#" class="more-link">Read more</a></p>
         </article>
         <article>
             <div class="article-image" style="background:url(srf1.jpg)"> </div>
             <h3 class="h">Surfing is actually good for you</h3>
             <p>All you need about surfing<a href="#" class="more-link">Read more</a></p>
           </article>

           <article >
             <div class="article-image" id="kapout" style="background:url(srf2.jpg)"></div>
             <h3 class="h">Learn surfing for you</h3>
             <p>All you need about surfing<a href="#" class="more-link bolded-link">Read more</a></p>
           </article>
         </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have 3 articles in a row and the third article is greater than other two. How can I fix this problem? I want to have the same size.

Comment: What do you mean by "greater than other two"? Have you inspected the css to see what rules are affecting the articles that do not match? You do not include the pertinent css so there isn't much for us to go on (my guess is that you have some css that either targets the first article or the others that you need to adjust).

Comment: Can you be more clear defining what is your problem?
Please have a look here since it's your first question. you can find many suggestions to help us to answer you. So you have more possibilities to get answers
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `flex` layout is a good option.

In the snippet bellow the `articles` are displayed in the same row. They have the same `width` and `height`.

I have added `padding` and `border` so you can see the `articles` boundaries.

```css
#top-stories{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
article {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<header id="main-header">
  <h1 id="site-title">Best News Ever!</h1>
</header>

<section id="top-stories">
  <article>
    <div class="article-image" style="background:url(srf.jpg)"> </div>
    <h3 class="h">Surfing all day</h3>
    <p>All you need about surfing<a href="#" class="more-link">Read more</a></p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="article-image" style="background:url(srf1.jpg)"> </div>
    <h3 class="h">Surfing is actually good for you</h3>
    <p>All you need about surfing<a href="#" class="more-link">Read more</a></p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <div class="article-image" id="kapout" style="background:url(srf2.jpg)"></div>
    <h3 class="h">Learn surfing for you</h3>
    <p>All you need about surfing you need about surfingyou need about surfingyou need about surfingyou need about surfingyou need about surfing<a href="#" class="more-link bolded-link">Read more</a></p>
  </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

If by the size you mean the same height you will need CSS for it.
Add this to your code and it should work.
You may have to show us the CSS for a better answer.

```
<style>
    article {
      height: 100px;
    }
</style>
```